# Can't open connection with connectionstring

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

This is connection string

```
<add name="dbdatabase" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLTSRV02;Initial Catalog=movies;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Class `connect`:

```
protected SqlConnection sqlcon;

public bool open_connection(string connection = "dbdatabase")
{
    sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connection].ToString());

    try 
    {  
        if(sqlcon.State.ToString()=="open")
        {
           sqlcon.Open();
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I can't get a connection to the database. Maybe I've made a mistake. Please help me find it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have "@" in your code ? Can you share your error message ?

Comment: ServerVersion = 'sqlcon.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Comment: Please complete your code and how you use it.

Comment: Your code only opens the connection if the connection is already open.

Comment: thank russ this the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking from the connection string, i believe you are using a Local DB .

Add your DB to the visual studio-server explorer( under data connections) and  then connect it. Then try debugging the code.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connection].ToString());
```

should be this:

```
sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connection].ConnectionString);
```

i.e. .ToString() is the wrong thing.

However, like @Guillaume, I'm confused by the @WebConfigurationManager part of it. It looks like it shouldn't compile...